# Break down this Angular tag

Tags: html, css, angular, tags

I have the following HTML tag using Angular:

`<div class='context-menu' #contextmenu [style.left.px]='this.newX' [style.top.px]='this.newY'>`

**What I Know:**

The class `context-menu` is applied.

**What I Want To Know:**

`#contextmenu`: What does this do? Is this an id?

`[style.left.px]`: What do the square brackets mean? And what could the dot notation in `styles.left.px` mean? ie. what kind of object could it be? I can't find `styles` elsewhere in the codebase.

`'this.newX'`: What kind of object could this be referring to? What does it mean to set `[style.left.px]` to `'this.newX'`?

Comment: Have you had a chance to read through the documentation on [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) first? Did you still have these questions after reading the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

what is **#contextMenu** ?

- this is template reference varibale of defined html tag. You can get reference of this tag in component file of .ts using this template reference variable using @ViewChild decorator.
  [Stack Blitz of @ViewChild](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

  ```
  @ViewChild('contextMenu') mainContent: any;
   public changeMainContent()
   {
         this.mainContent.nativeElement.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
   }
  ```

above code changes color of div element when button click of changeMainContent() event fires. 
What is **[style.left.px]** ?

- This is style property bing. [style.left.px]="this.newX" here, property of newX is dynamically assign to css left pixel using style property binding. more you can find out here in this [Link](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/attribute-class-style-bindings-angular)

have a look at this [StackBlitz of style binding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-style-binding)